# Serialize object into JSON but only include properties with the [DataMember] attribute

Tags: c#, json

How can I serialize the given object into JSON but only include properties with the [DataMember] attribute.

```
User MyUser = new User();
string MessageJson = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(MyUser);

public class User
{
    [DataMember]
    public string username { get; set; }

    public string password { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) for that.
Note that, I think you'll also need `DataContract` attribute on the class.

Comment: I'll answer the above comment - yes you can.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [JSON.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/10/23/efficient-json-with-json-net-reducing-serialized-json-size).

> If a class has many properties and you only want to serialize a small subset of them then adding JsonIgnore to all the others will be tedious and error prone. The way to tackle this scenario is to add the DataContractAttribute to the class and DataMemberAttributes to the properties to serialize. This is opt-in serialization, only the properties you mark up with be serialized, compared to opt-out serialization using JsonIgnoreAttribute.

```
[DataContract]
public class Computer
{
  // included in JSON
  [DataMember]
  public string Name { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public decimal SalePrice { get; set; }

  // ignored
  public string Manufacture { get; set; }
  public int StockCount { get; set; }
  public decimal WholeSalePrice { get; set; }
  public DateTime NextShipmentDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I was hoping to use .Net native objects. But looks like this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can place the `[ScriptIgnore]` attribute on the properties that you do not want to include in your result.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question the OP is asking.