# WCF returned json list also needs the name for the list

Tags: c#, .net, json, wcf

I built a WCF web api (.Net 4.5) that responds to a GET from http://localhost:62633/returnsdesk
and returns a json list.

> [{"Name":"reject","status":"FULL"},{"Name":"returns","status":"OK"}]

However to be better formatted the json look like:

> {"destinations":
>   [{"destinationName":"reject","status":"FULL"},{"destinationName":"StevesDesk","status":"OK"}]
>   }

I have no idea how to google this.

How do I get WCF to WebGet & WebMessageFormat.Json to name the json list?

Comment: How is the title related to your question?

Comment: You're correct about the questions name.  I'll fix that right now.  Not sure where that came from.  Thanks.

Comment: @Will No.  Not hand edited.  `[{"Name":"reject","status":"FULL"},{"Name":"returns","status":"OK"}]` is the string WCF returns.  Byte-by-byte.  but the problem is there isn't a name for the list included.

Comment: Are you in control of the WCF service?  If so, you can control the type being serialized and switch it out for one that would return what you want.  If you don't control it, then you have to deal.

Comment: I built the service.  I own it.  I don't know how to force WCF to include the list's name in what WCF returns in the response.  In WCF you decorate your object's class attributes with [DataContract].  That gets you the "name" & "status" (because those are the names of the attributes) when you return List<objs>.  But how do I get WCF to also include a name attribute for the list itself in json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really belongs to @user1892538

Take the type that was being serialized and returned by WCF in a list (`List<Desk>`) and wrap that in another type such as:

```
[DataContract]
    public class retDesks { [DataMember] public List<Desk> destinations; }
```

Now WCF returns the desired name:

> {"destinations":
>   [{"ID":1,"destinationName":"reject","status":"FULL"},{"ID":2,
>   "destinationName":"StevesDesk","status":"OK"}] }

But you will also notice the Json `Desk` object also now includes the attribute `ID`.  Before `ID` was hidden from the output by the definition of `Desk` because `ID` was not decorated with `[DataMember]`.

Now however, decorations on `Desk` don't matter because the entire `Desk` type is exposed given that `retDesks` has `[DataMember] List<Desk>`.

So how do you deal with that?
The most loved quick suggestion, use Linq to filter out properties of the `List<Desks>` as in:

```
var d1 = _desks.Select(e => new { e.destinationName, e.status } );
```

Bad news here is `d1` is a list of an anonymous type.
This is not acceptable to the definition of `retDesks` type which contains the `List<Desks>`.

So ... create a third type `public deskRet [ public string destinationName; public string status; }` and set this type up as a list between the Linq's output and the instance of the returned type `retDesks`.

```
public class Desk { public int ID; public string destinationName; public string status; }

public class retDesks { [DataMember] public List<deskRet> destinations; }

public class deskRet { public string destinationName; public string status; }

...

List<deskRet> d1 = _desks.Select(e => 
    new deskRet{ destinationName=e.destinationName, status=e.status } 
    ).ToList<deskRet>(); // maybe I'm working to hard to guarantee the type.  But I'm okay with that
return(new retDesks{ destinations=d1 };
```

At the end of the day you have the spec'ed output:

> {"destinations": [{"destinationName":"reject","status":"FULL"},{
>   "destinationName":"StevesDesk","status":"OK"}] }

But next time consider a third-party framework like Json.NET.  Or, only maybe, a custom Json Serialzer using the .Net WCF Framework.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have a method, decorated with

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
       RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
       ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
       UriTemplate = "returnsDesk")]
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
```

returning a `List<Desk>`.

```
public List<Desk> GetDesks()
{
```

You need to return a new class `DeskList` with a `[DataMember]` decorated `destinations` property, defined as  `List<Desk>`, containing such a list, instead.

Comment: All your assumptions are correct.  This is a GET.  I even tried the `  [return: MessageParameter(Name = "balbal")]`decoration (didn't work here, but I wish it did.  The ability to programatically customize this attribute would be nice).  The rest of what you are saying make sense and I will try that later and get back to you here.  Somehow I just kind of thought that that just happened for Lists<T> anyway, and was surprised to see it wasn't.

Comment: @user1892539 Worked like a charm but one thing maybe you have a tip for.  My internal class `Desk` has attributes that were not exposed to json before by their not having the [DataMember] decoration.  Of course now, All of those attributes are being included in the json output even though the `Desk` class itself still only has 'destinationName' & 'status' decorated with [DataMember].  I honestly didn;t see this one coming.

Comment: Looks like you're asking this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092802/serialize-object-into-json-but-only-include-properties-with-the-datamember-att), aren't you?

Comment: Yes and no.  I don't see where they were concerned with the whole class containing a list and how to hide some of the properties of the list'ed class.  But the do point out json.net which I might serialze the list then pass that string to the class that is being returned because of your tip.  Thanks.

Comment: A workaround could be using Linq `Select` into a wrapper `DeskModel` class  with those json relevant properties only

Comment: Use Linq to filter the unneeded properties!.  Totally right.  That is what I'll do tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

> credits for the **LongNameContractResolver** go to [Bryon Rogers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20622492/how-to-ignore-jsonpropertypropertyname-somename-when-serializing-json)

Hi, you can use the **NewtonSoft.Json** reference to serialize and deserialize objects

**Take a look at the code below to answer your question**

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace JsonNamedList
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Destinations object
            var destinations = MockGetDestinations();
            //Destinations object as Json string, use the LongNameContractResolver to ignore the Json Property Name
            var strDestinationsJson = LongNameContractResolver.Serialize(destinations, true);
            //Print the destinations Json to output
            Console.WriteLine(strDestinationsJson);
            //Stop closing the console window
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static Destinations MockGetDestinations()
        {
            //[{"Name":"reject","status":"FULL"},{"Name":"returns","status":"OK"}]
            var apiResponse = "[{'Name':'reject','status':'FULL'},{ 'Name':'returns','status':'OK'}]".Replace("'", "\"");
            var wrappedApiResponse = WrapIntoDestinations(apiResponse);
            //destinations as object
            var destinations = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Destinations>(wrappedApiResponse);

            return destinations;
        }

        static string WrapIntoDestinations(string apiResponse) => $"{{'destinations': {apiResponse} }}".Replace("'", "\"");
    }

    public class Destination
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Name")]
        public string destinationName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "status")]
        public string status { get; set; }
    }
    public class Destinations
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "destinations")]
        public IEnumerable<Destination> destinations { get; set; }
    }
    public class LongNameContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
    {
        protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
        {
            // Let the base class create all the JsonProperties 
            // using the short names
            IList<JsonProperty> list = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);

            // Now inspect each property and replace the 
            // short name with the real property name
            foreach (JsonProperty prop in list)
            {
                prop.PropertyName = prop.UnderlyingName;
            }

            return list;
        }
        public static string Serialize(object obj, bool useLongNames)
        {
            JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
            settings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            if (useLongNames)
            {
                settings.ContractResolver = new LongNameContractResolver();
            }

            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, settings);
        }
    }
}
```

**This produces the following output (Json String)**
[image]